# Python + Selenium: Wait until element is fully loaded

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

So I have been trying to play around with the function in Selenium that is called:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="accountStandalone"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/button')))
wait.click()
```

Before I'm starting to say the issue. What I'm trying to do a Selenium of is to basically make a Selenium that automatic write to the forumlar in this picture:

[image: Pic1]

Which isn't any complications. However whenever I press "Skapa Konto", It loads and waits until a new page comes up which is:

[image: Pic2]

Which is the picture above. My idea is that what I wish is that it should wait until it gives me that "picture" (Which is the same link so it doesn't make any changes) so I assume better to do is to wait until a text etc "FORTSÄTT or HELLO" is the browser. Then continue.

However, I'm having an issue when trying using this. The reason is that it doesn't wait until it found but goes instant and does other stuff which it shouldn't. Right now it just skips the wait like the function doesn't work or is there at all. What did I do for wrong?

---

Update:

What I know is that whenever I try to register on the website - The website doesn't change meaning it takes me to a new page when its been a successful account. But it does automatic refresh and saying its been successful. So meaning that somehow I want to make something in a way that it checks and sees if something new happened to the page. If not, Wait again and try again?... Something like that?

What I would do is etc check if there is:

```
<div class="confirmation-title nsg-font-family--platform nsg-text--black edf-title-font-size--xlarge js-confirmationTitle">NU ÄR DU MEDLEM, Hello.</div>
```

or

```
<button type="button" class="nsg-button nsg-bg--black register-next-step-cta js-nextStepCta">FORTSÄTT</button>
```

However the problem is as I said, whenever I press "SKAPA KONTO" - It just waits for the server to double check and then automatic refreshes the page and says successful.

Comment: Can you remove the .wait after WebDriverWait and try. According to the official documentation, it should be  element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))

Comment: @CDNthe2nd Seems you are victim of a brittle absolute _xpath_. Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: Did not work @Satish - I will update my question in a few minutes for both of you!

Comment: Done! @DebanjanB! I hope I did correctly or something that you meant!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I strongly believe you were pretty close. You simply need to format your code in a *Pythonic* which may solve your issue straight away as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="accountStandalone"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/button'))).click()
```

You have pulled a rug over the actual issue by mentioning *it doesn't wait until it found but goes instant and does other stuff which it shouldn't* rather than mentioning what your program is supposed to do (e.g. *your code trials*) and what wrong your program is doing (i.e. *error stack trace*).

As per the *HTMLs* you have shared you can induce a waiter for either of the *WebElements* as follows :

- Waiter for the visibility of the text **NU ÄR DU MEDLEM, Hello.** :

  - CSS_SELECTOR :

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.confirmation-title.nsg-font-family--platform.nsg-text--black.edf-title-font-size--xlarge.js-confirmationTitle")))
    ```
  - XPATH :

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='confirmation-title nsg-font-family--platform nsg-text--black edf-title-font-size--xlarge js-confirmationTitle' and contains(.,'NU ÄR DU MEDLEM, Hello.')]")))
    ```
- Waiter for the button with text **FORTSÄTT** :

  - CSS_SELECTOR :

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.nsg-button.nsg-bg--black.register-next-step-cta.js-nextStepCta")))
    ```
  - XPATH :

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='nsg-button nsg-bg--black register-next-step-cta js-nextStepCta' and contains(.,'FORTSÄTT')]")))
    ```

Comment: Ohhh there we go! Yeah that actually helped! Now it does what I wished for. I really do appreciate it and I can't thank you more than enough!